# How to send my most recent dataset by FTP?

Tags: ftp, dataset, mainframe, tso

I am using IBM Mainframe TSO to view files from a dataset. I recently have been told to start FTPing the latest generation dataset everyday to a folder on my desktop. The problem is that the FTP script I have only lets me FTP a file with the exact name I put. Everyday the dataset changes.

How can I write a script that will FTP the latest generation? Please see example below of how the dataset changes:

Dataset

```
8/30/18 - KIBI.AL242422.REPORT.G6441V00
8/31/18-  KIBI.AL242422.REPORT.G6442V00
9/1/18 -  KIBI.AL242422.REPORT.G6443V00
9/4/18 -  KIBI.AL242422.REPORT.G6444V00
9/5/18 -  KIBI.AL242422.REPORT.G6445V00
```

command.bat

```
ftp -i -s:Command.txt
quit
```

command.txt

```
open sc01.sample.com
USER NAME
PASSWORD
get 'KIBI.AL242422.REPORT.G6441V00'
```

Comment: What is the client you are using?  You should be able to access 'KIBI.AL242422.REPORT(0)' and the host would resolve that for you.

Comment: Will this work?  In the FTP Client

`cd /KIBI` and then  `get AL242422.REPORT(0)`.  Are you pulling from the mainframe or pushing?  What client are you using?

Comment: @Hogstrom if he is using windows cmd and zOS using the relative GDG as you suggested will work. I do this everyday. It will resolve the relative name to the fully qualified name

Comment: Hi Hogstrom this worked. Thank you very much! Just had to add the "(0)'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What your referring to are Generation Data Groups.  You can refer to the files in relative form where `(0)` is the most current.  `(-1)` is the previous generation, etc.  In your case you want to access the dataset by relative reference.  In your FTP client do the following:

`cd KIBI`

`get AL242422.REPORT(0)`

The system will determine which of the datasets is the one you want.  Its a nice feature.

Comment: As an aside the reader should be extremely aware that without the subscript you will get them ALL as a concatenation.